# Angular no encuentra la ruta por ID

Tags: javascript, angular, api

Tengo la API en node, y responde a todas las peticiones e inclusive con parametro "id", cree el servicio en angular, llamo el metodo en el componente y a la hora de querer llamar el objeto "id", no se muestra por la consola y me manda el siguiente error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'alq/63351',

app-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'alq',
    component: AlquileresComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'fds',
    component: FdsComponent
  }, 
  {
    path: 'inv',
    component: InventarioComponent
  }
];
```

Servicio.ts

```
getOneRent(id: number) {
const path = `http://localhost:3000/api/alq/${id}`;
return this.http.get<Alquiler>(path);
}
```

Componente.ts

```
export class AlquileresComponent implements OnInit {

  alquiler: Alquiler[] = [];
  dataone: Alquiler;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fetchAlq() {
    this.dataService.getAllAlq()
    .subscribe(alquiler => {
      this.alquiler = alquiler;
      console.log(alquiler);
    });
  }

  FetchOneRent(id: number) {
    this.dataService.getOneRent(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataone = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Html.component

```
<div *ngFor="let items of dataone.recordsets">
  <ng-container *ngIf="items.length;else printData" >
    <pre *ngFor="let item of items">{{item | json}}</pre>
    <br>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #printData>
    <pre>{{items |json}}</pre>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

No lo muestra, ni por consola, ni tampoco lo renderiza. 
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/alq/63336
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Consulta: ¿En tu código se usa la interface `ActivatedRoute` para obtener los parámetros de la URL?

Comment: @cristiancajiaos, yo creo, que no , donde se define eso? app-routing?

Comment: intenta cambiar el path a algo como `path: 'alq/:id',`